# Why serial port write is not working with for loop?

Tags: node.js, express, for-loop, serial-port

I'm building a RESTful API for serial port communication with cash register through Node.js. The main idea is that a web application will send an array with commands and the rest api (stored locally on a machine with a cash register) will send every command to the register one at time. After every command the serial port (the cash register) should send back a message with the status.
My problem is with the write function to the port.

When I send the array with the commands (currently 5 in total but they can be N) I'm trying to send each command in a for loop. I have set a timeout so there is some waiting period between each command. The problem is that only the first (and sometimes the second) command is being send.
But if I manually send each command everything works as expected.

The commented part is the one I'm trying to make it work and the uncommented is the one working now. It's not suitable as it's hard coded.

```
app.post('/write', function (req, res) {
    var commands = req.body.cmd;
    if(commands === '') res.json({error: '450'});
    var cmdLength = commands.length;

   /* for (let i = 0; i < commands.length; i++){
        setTimeout(() => {
            sendCmd(commands[i]);
            console.log(commands[i]);
            readData();
            if(i == cmdLength){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    res.json({fp : receivedData});
                }, 750)
            }
        }, 750)
     //   timeout(commands[i]);
    }*/

    if (commands instanceof Array){
        console.log('in if');
        sendCmd(commands[0]);
        readData();
        setTimeout(() => {
            sendCmd(commands[1]);
            readData();
            setTimeout(() => {
                sendCmd(commands[2]);
                readData();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    sendCmd(commands[3]);
                    readData();
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        sendCmd(commands[4]);
                        readData();
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            res.json({fp: receivedData});
                        }, 750)
                    }, 750)
                }, 750)
            }, 500)
        }, 500)

    }else{
        sendCmd(commands);
        readData();
        setTimeout(() => {
            res.json({fp: '200'});
        }, 500)
    }
    serialPort.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
        console.log('Unhandled Rejection at: Promise', p, 'reason:', reason);
    });
});

function sendCmd(cmd){
    serialPort.write(cmd);
}
function readData(){
    receivedData = '';
    serialPort.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        receivedData += data.toString('hex');
    })
}
```

Obviously the manual method is not desirable and it would be perfect if somebody could point me to the problem. I think it's something with trying to write while the previous one is not done (that's why there are timeouts) but I'm not sure as this is my first time working with nodejs, serial ports and cash registers.

Comment: The for loop will not work like that. I'm sure all the `console.log(commands[i]);` print output at the same time, not every 750ms. Your timeout time should be `750 * i`

Comment: @Molda I'm not sure why it worked but it did. I'm wondering if I move the result json after the for loop and add to it a time out something like `750 * commands.length` will it return the last buffer?

Comment: @Molda Never mind, I figured it out. Can you post your answer so I can mark it as accepted? Thank you, for your help!